# How can I pass in a SwiftUI View in a function?

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, uikit, protocols

The app I'm working on is predominantly in UIKit. We are starting to shift to SwiftUI for smaller components and I wanted to write a neat little extension which would take in a SwiftUI view and return the UIKit view. This is the code I currently have:

```
    static func getUIView(for swiftUIView: View) -> UIView {
        let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
        return hostingController.view
    }
}
```

However this throws an error

> Protocol 'View' can only be used as a generic constraint because it has Self or associated type requirements

Could someone explain to me why this is a problem and what would be the right way of achieving this?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You simply need to make your method generic and restrict your generic type to `View`.

```
static func getUIView<V: View>(for swiftUIView: V) -> UIView {
    let hostingController = UIHostingController(rootView: swiftUIView)
    return hostingController.view
}
```

However, I'd rather suggest creating a computed property on `View` that returns a `UIView` from the view itself.

```
extension View {
    var uiView: UIView {
        UIHostingController(rootView: self).view
    }
}
```

And then call it on the `View` you want to convert to `UIView`:

```
Text("Label").uiView
```

Comment: Beautiful. Thanks!